# QGIS 2.10 - Web server - Tiles

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, qgis-web-client

It's posible to automaticly generate tiles from QGIS web server ?

I need export a project (europe size) from zoom 9 to 13 in png Format in order to use it with leaflet like.
I tried many extention that are not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

The `QTiles` plugin should deliver what you want. You have to allow for experimental plugins to get it.

If you want the tiles inside leaflet in the usual World Mercator projection, set EPSG:3857 as **project** CRS before starting the plugin.

Comment: Thx, but as I said : No plug is working well... our project is using label and many other options that qtile dont handle well... like different layer show according zoom level.

Comment: You can specify that the plugin shall only render one zoom level with the current layout, then change the layout and proceed with the next zoom level(s).

Comment: But when rendering the labels that cover 2 tiles, there is a problem when the ref point is close to the tile edge. I.E. On "border" tile = no label, On tile including the point = label is render but cut.